# Memory leaks on Listener passed to RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: java, android

I have a question about possible memory leaks passing a listener to a RecyclerView Adapter. If I implement an interface in my activity (my listener), and I pass this activity as parameter to a RecyclerView adapter, will I have problems with that listener if the activity is destroyed, or will it be destroyed when the activity finish?

Eg::

`

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListener {

@overrides
public void onCreate (blablabla) {

MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter (this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);
}}
```

`

Sorry for the code but Im writing with my mobile phone. Can anyone argue if I will have problems with memory or cyclics? 
Thank you!

Comment: As long as your adapter does not survive, it won't leak the activity.

Comment: Depends on what you do with context in the "MyAdapter".

Comment: I just implement a Listener in the Activity, I pass the listener to the Adapter and just performs Synchronous actions with it. (EG: Notify onClick of a cell, and then in the Activity I Implement the interface)